Extend "grid-lines" beyond a CSS grid
Assuming an N-by-M grid of cells, how can I achieve the below effect.
I can make a 3x3 grid fine.
[A][B][C]
[D][E][F]
[G][H][I]

Adding gap spaces the elements out:
[A] [B] [C]

[D] [E] [F]

[G] [H] [I]

And I can fill the background to give the effect of grid-lines.
.-----------.
|[A]|[B]|[C]|
|---+---+---|
|[D]|[E]|[F]|
|---+---+---|
|[G]|[H]|[I]|
`-----------`

But is it possible to have grid-lines align within the gaps of a grid, and also "extend" beyond the grid by a set amount?
  |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+--
  |[A]|[B]|[C]|
--+---+---+---+--
  |[D]|[E]|[F]|
--+---+---+---+--
  |[G]|[H]|[I]|
--+---+---+---+--
  |   |   |   |

I've managed to "hack it" with absolutely positioned DIVs using formulas which reference the grid's custom properties to align themselves. But this requires me to know the number of rows ahead of time & insert HTML elements just for styling. Figured there must be a better way.


    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .grid-wrapper {
      --grid-margin: 10px;
      --grid-cell-size: 100px;
      --grid-line-thickness: 2px;
      --grid-line-offset: calc(0px - var(--grid-line-thickness));
      
      --grid-color: darkgray;
      --grid-line-color: gray;
      
      position: relative;
      margin: var(--grid-margin);
      width: calc(3 * var(--grid-cell-size));
    }

    .grid {
      display: grid;
      gap: var(--grid-line-thickness);
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, var(--grid-cell-size));
      grid-auto-rows: var(--grid-cell-size);
    }

    .grid > div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: var(--grid-color);
    }

    .grid-line-row {
      width: 110%;
      left: -5%;
      position: absolute;
      height: var(--grid-line-thickness);
      background: var(--grid-line-color);
      top: var(--grid-line-offset);
    }

    .grid-line-row:nth-child(2) {
      top: calc(var(--grid-line-offset) + 
        var(--grid-line-thickness) + 
        var(--grid-cell-size));
    }

    .grid-line-row:nth-child(3) {
      top: calc(var(--grid-line-offset) + 
        2 * var(--grid-line-thickness) + 
        2 * var(--grid-cell-size));
    }

    .grid-line-row:nth-child(4) {
      top: calc(var(--grid-line-offset) + 
        3 * var(--grid-line-thickness) + 
        3 * var(--grid-cell-size));
    }

    .grid-line-col {
      height: 110%;
      top: -5%;
      position: absolute;
      width: var(--grid-line-thickness);
      background: var(--grid-line-color);
      left: var(--grid-line-offset);
    }

    .grid-line-col:nth-child(6) {
      left: calc(var(--grid-line-offset) +
        var(--grid-line-thickness) + 
        var(--grid-cell-size));
    }

    .grid-line-col:nth-child(7) {
      left: calc(var(--grid-line-offset) + 
        2 * var(--grid-line-thickness) + 
        2 * var(--grid-cell-size));
    }

    .grid-line-col:nth-child(8) {
      left: calc(var(--grid-line-offset) +
        3 * var(--grid-line-thickness) + 
        3 * var(--grid-cell-size));
    }
<body>
    <div class="grid-wrapper">
        <div class="grid">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-line-row"></div>
        <div class="grid-line-row"></div>
        <div class="grid-line-row"></div>
        <div class="grid-line-row"></div>
        <div class="grid-line-col"></div>
        <div class="grid-line-col"></div>
        <div class="grid-line-col"></div>
        <div class="grid-line-col"></div>
    </div>
</body>




I would just have an extra grid row top and bottom, and an extra grid column left and right, and then have those lines as borders. You can set how wide/tall those extra rows and columns are.

@ralph.m - Yeah right. So instead of a 3xN, make it a 5x(N+2), and then always just use 4 lines (or even a negatively positioned box-shadow) to "hide" the edges of the grid, and then the outer rows just have background: <whatever> so that you only see the grid-lines? The only thing there would be an nth-child or equivalent selector to force grid items into the middle 3 columns & skip the first / last row, yeah? Or would you still need empty <div>'s to fill the gaps? Was hoping for something "generic" based on how many columns I need & if the number of rows was just "data dependent."

Here is an idea that should work with any number of rows/columns. I am relying on a single pseudo element and gradients to create the lines.


.grid {
  --cell-size: 100px;
  --line-thickness: 2px;
  --line-offset: 8px;
  --line-color: gray;
  
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--line-thickness);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, var(--cell-size));
  grid-auto-rows: var(--cell-size);
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.grid:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: calc(-1*var(--line-offset));
  --c: var(--line-color) 0 var(--line-thickness),
      #0000 0 calc(var(--cell-size) + var(--line-thickness));
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,var(--c)) 
      calc(var(--line-offset) - var(--line-thickness)) 0/
      calc(100% - 2*var(--line-offset) + 2*var(--line-thickness)) 100%,
    repeating-linear-gradient(var(--c)) 
      0 calc(var(--line-offset) - var(--line-thickness))/
      100% calc(100% - 2*var(--line-offset) + 2*var(--line-thickness));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
}
.grid > div {
  background: darkgrey;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>




This is perfect, thanks Temani! The gradients are a little bit "black magic" to me, but I'll use MDN & fiddle with them to understand how they work. A repeating background was something I didn't even consider. This is easily scaling with number of items / columns. If I want to adjust the height or width of the cells independently of one another I can create a second --c var & swap out --cell-size. Only thing I needed was to add print-color-adjust: exact; to the grid as some elements were coming in "white" but only when printing from my browser.
